# Turn Ruby array into strings - problem with my code?

Tags: ruby

I want to turn this array of cards into a string (output I want is at the bottom) Here's my code:

```
  # Returns an array of 5 cards in player's hand:
  # =>  Eg: ['6♠', '3♦', 'A♣', 'J♦', 'J♥']
  private
  def cards
    %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥)
  end

  def to_s
    cards.map {|card| "-" + card.to_s}.join("-")
    end
end
```

The output I want is a string of the cards like this: - 6♠ - 3♦ - A♣ - J♦ - J♥ -

Comment: Try `arr = %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥); "- #{arr.join(' - ')} -" #=> "- 6♠ - 3♦ - A♣ - J♦ - J♥ -"`.

Comment: Your question could use some clarification.  For one thing, your code is incomplete and looks like a snippet from a larger code section that doesn't work on its own.  There is an extra ```end```, and the call to ```private``` doesn't make sense where it is.

Comment: ...also, you should show what output you're actually getting.  It could be that you're just getting an error because your code is incomplete, or it could be that your string formatting is wrong.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is currently posed, you have 3 things going wrong:

First, you're trying to create private methods without first calling a `class`.  This also explains the extra `end`.  To fix that, we can add the class call at the beginning like so:

```
class Test

private
  def cards
    %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥)
  end

  def to_s
    cards.map {|card| "-" + card.to_s}.join("-")
    end
end
```

Second, we need to actually use the class somehow.  We can use `Class.new` for this, like so:

```
class Test

private
  def cards
    %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥)
  end

  def to_s
    cards.map {|card| "-" + card.to_s}.join("-")
    end
end

puts Test.new
#=>  "-6♠--3♦--A♣--J♦--J♥"
```

I can only assume your posted code section was just incomplete, that you weren't having issues with the first couple things, and that you're just having problems with the formatting in that output line.  If so, there are many different ways to do this, but your main issue is the following section of your code:

`"-" + card.to_s}.join("-")`

You are iterating over the array and adding a `"-"` before every element.  You are then joining up those elements with a redundant `"-"` to create your string.  You need to get rid of one or the other.  I suggest just getting rid of the latter like so:

`cards.map {|card| "-" + card.to_s}.join`

Its also worth noting that your array elements are already strings, so the `.to_s` is unnecessary.  Your line could therefore be reduced to:

`cards.map {|card| "-" + card}.join`

This will result in `#=> "-6♠-3♦-A♣-J♦-J♥"`

The only thing missing now is that last dash.  To fix that, we just add the dash independently at the end of your newly joined array like so:

`cards.map {|card| "-" + card}.join + "-"`

The completed test would then look like this:

```
class Test

private
  def cards
    %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥)
  end

  def to_s
    cards.map {|card| "-" + card}.join + "-"
    end
end

puts Test.new
#=>  "-6♠-3♦-A♣-J♦-J♥-"
```

At the end of the day though, your string formatting issues could essentially be addressed by just replacing `("-")` with `+"-"`

Answer (score 0):

### Join with Format String

From inside a class, you can do this fairly easily with a combination of `cards.join` and a format string. For example:

```rb
def cards
  %w(6♠ 3♦ A♣ J♦ J♥)
end

def to_s
  sprintf "- %s -", cards.join(" - ")
end
```

You can test this in irb outside of a class by defining your #cards method, and then invoking [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) with the format string and the String formed by joining your cards as arguments.

```rb
sprintf "- %s -", cards.join(" - ")
#=> "- 6♠ - 3♦ - A♣ - J♦ - J♥ -"
```

There are other interpolation methods available as well, such as [Kernel#format](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format), embedded expressions, and %-style interpolation expressions, but this seems both simple and well-supported with any reasonably recent Ruby version.